# Parse returned C# list in AJAX success function

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, webforms

I am using web forms and I have a webmethod in the code behind that my ajax function is calling. It appears that the webmethod is returning data but I am having trouble parsing the returned json string into table rows

Here is my code behind method (Web Method):

```
public class Part
{
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string NetAvailable { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public string Distance { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
}

[WebMethod]
public static List<Part> GetParts(string partnumber)
{
    List<Part> parts = new List<Part>();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["NXT"].ToString()))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT prod, qtyonhand, whse, listprice FROM icsw where prod LIKE @partnumber", con))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@partnumber", "%" + partnumber + "%");

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Part part = new Part
                    {
                        Number = reader[0].ToString(),
                        Price = reader[3].ToString(),
                        NetAvailable = reader[1].ToString(),
                        Distance = "0.0",
                        Location = reader[2].ToString(),
                        Phone = GetBranchPhoneNumber(reader[2].ToString())
                    };
                    parts.Add(part);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    return parts;
}
```

Here is my AJAX call:

```
$("#searchbtn").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'partslocator.aspx/GetParts',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify({ 'partnumber': $("#searchtbx").val()}),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {

            for (var i in data) {
                alert(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
                $('#searchresultstble').append("<tr><td>" + data[i].Number + "</td><td>" + data[i].Price + "</td><td>" + data[i].NetAvailable + "</td><td>" + data[i].Location + "</td><td>" + data[i].Distance + "</td><td>" + data[i].Phone + "</td></tr>");
            }
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(xhr.status);
            alert(thrownError);
        }
    });
});
```

Here is what data is coming back as:

```
{"d":[{"__type":"partslocator+Part","Number":"0-2809 1025","Price":"2.50000","NetAvailable":"0.00","Location":"82pk","Distance":"0.0","Phone":"test"},{"__type":"partslocator+Part","Number":"0-2809 1025","Price":"2.58000","NetAvailable":"0.00","Location":"Phx","Distance":"0.0","Phone":"test"}]}
```

Why am I getting undefined for all the rows that are being added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll note that the returned `data` is not actually an array, but an object with a value (`d`) that contains that array. Try this:

```
    success: function (returnedData) {
        var data = returnedData.d;
        for (var i in data) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(data[i]));
            $('#searchresultstble').append("<tr><td>" + data[i].Number + "</td><td>" + data[i].Price + "</td><td>" + data[i].NetAvailable + "</td><td>" + data[i].Location + "</td><td>" + data[i].Distance + "</td><td>" + data[i].Phone + "</td></tr>");
        }
    },
```

Comment: how for loop work without increment please explain me 
your ans is worng

Comment: @darshandave: This is [JavaScript's `for...in` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).